# Possible to Backfill Firestore <> Big Query Using HTTP Transform

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

We are currently using the Stream Firestore to Big Query extension.

The extension indicates "This extension only sends the content of documents that have been changed", and provides documentation for backfilling historical collection data using the fs-bq-import-collection script.

For new data, we have successfully implemented the "Transform" function, using an HTTP Cloud Function to provide Big Query with the transformed data we would look to see.

However, when we run the backfill script, the transform http function is not triggered.

Is there a method to backfill firestore data to big query, while also leveraging the Transform function?